# How can I force the phone screen to stay on

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I flashed Ubuntu for phones on a device and would like the display to stay on while I take photographs or video of the device. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Either, on the device in the terminal app issue the command:-

```
stop powerd
```

Alternatively from a computer connected to the device, with the android tools installed issue:-

```
adb shell stop powerd
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, from:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Testing

```
# Run this in another terminal window and leave it running to
# make sure display stays on for the tests:
adb shell powerd-cli display on bright
```