# How can I disable the screen-saver on tablet with Ubuntu Touch Saucy?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lock-screen

How can I disable screen-saver Ubuntu Touch Saucy on my phone or tablet (Nexus 7) ?

I do play a internet radio streaming with the mplayer (from terminal application). Unfortunately the tablet stop play (and the screen gets black) after a while (30-60 seconds). Playback does continue when leave my bath, press the power button (wake up the system) and switch back the terminal application to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

From this post:
[How can I force the phone screen to stay on](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360575/how-can-i-force-the-phone-screen-to-stay-on)

```
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ sudo stop powerd
```

That works for me. But if powerd is stopped, the device won't suspend using the power button.

Or you can do this:
    # Run this in another terminal window and leave it running to
    # make sure display stays on for the tests:
    adb shell powerd-cli display on bright

from: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Testing

Answer (score 0):

Note: I only tried this in 14.10, but it might also work in previous versions.

I had a closer look on `powerd-cli` and it seems that it has an option to disable powersaving:

`sudo powerd-cli active &` (Run this command in the Terminal-app on the phone.)

This will prohibit that apps are stopped, but the screen can be turned off as usual. (The `&` is needed so that powerd-cli runs in the background - otherwise powerd-cli runs in the terminal and you couldn't enter any other commands.)

To re-enable powersaving enter the command `fg` and press Ctrl+C.

For 16.04 (ubports) `repowerd-cli active &` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is an app in the store called `Active Screen` which provides a workaround for these kind of issues. 
It's nothing more than a switch, that you toggle to tell your screen to stay active.